# What is the name of the email template which an administrator will receive when he/she change an order?

Tags: email, magento, templates

When an administrator want to edit/change an order, the order will be canceled and a new order will be created. After completing the order, the administrator receives a New Order mail. From my experience this is a different email then a customer receives when he/she completes a new order.
I would like to customize the admin "changed order" email. Where can I find it?

Comment: did you find the new order email send to admin?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?